# Unexpected builtin logger behaviour: Duplication for logger names with '.'

Tags: python, logging

It appears that the builtin python logger is splitting on every `'.'` and duplicating the logger multiple times.

```
In [1]: import logging, pprint

In [2]: logging.getLogger('\\\\my\\path\\to\\file.py')
Out[2]: <Logger \\my\path\to\file.py (WARNING)>

In [3]: pprint.pprint(logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict)
{'TerminalIPythonApp': <Logger TerminalIPythonApp (WARNING)>,
 '\\\\my\\path\\to\\file': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x00000000066F34E0>,
 '\\\\my\\path\\to\\file.py': <Logger \\my\path\to\file.py (WARNING)>,
 'asyncio': <Logger asyncio (WARNING)>,
 'concurrent': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x0000000003F81128>,
 'concurrent.futures': <Logger concurrent.futures (WARNING)>,
 'parso': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x0000000004E73748>,
 'parso.cache': <Logger parso.cache (WARNING)>,
 'parso.python': <logging.PlaceHolder object at 0x000000000465CEF0>,
 'parso.python.diff': <Logger parso.python.diff (WARNING)>}
```

Why is this being done? Is this an intended feature?

**Edit**
There appears to be no reference to this in the docs other than that the name is *typically* hierarchical like `a`, `a.b`. This implies nothing about duplicate logs

> **`logging.getLogger`**`(name=None)`
>
> Return a logger with the specified name
>   or, if name is None, return a logger which is the root logger of the
>   hierarchy. If specified, the name is typically a dot-separated
>   hierarchical name like ‘a’, ‘a.b’ or ‘a.b.c.d’. Choice of these names
>   is entirely up to the developer who is using logging.
>
> All calls to this function with a given name return the same logger
>   instance. This means that logger instances never need to be passed
>   between different parts of an application.

Comment: Why are you passing a file path as the name of a logger? Logger names are dot-separated strings of names.

Comment: As often is the case, one has to deal with other people's code. As per docs, logger names are **not expected** to be strings of names, rather, they are **typically** strings of names

Comment: The point being, the `.` has special meaning, as the names define a hierarchy of loggers. `'\\\\my\\path\\to\\file.py'` is a logger named `py` that is the child of a logger named `'\\\\my\\path\\to\\file'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The name is potentially a period-separated hierarchical value, like
>   foo.bar.baz (though it could also be just plain foo, for example).
>   Loggers that are further down in the hierarchical list are children of
>   loggers higher up in the list. For example, given a logger with a name
>   of foo, loggers with names of foo.bar, foo.bar.baz, and foo.bam are
>   all descendants of foo.

from the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html it's the second paragraph under logger objects. So the dot in the name makes it a logger further down the hierarchy

Comment: thanks I didn't see that part. The docs still don't address the fact that they will create loggers throughout the hierarchy if they don't yet exist so perhaps that needs to be improved